# Subnets, range of subnets an broadcast address

Tags: subnet

I need to create a 5 subnets for minimum 25 computers.
The ip address is **192.168.1.0**, subnet mask  **255.255.255.0**

**My results:**

192.168.1.0   => (range of subnets) 192.168.1.1- 192.168.1.30 => (broadcast address) 
192.168.1.31

192.168.1.32  => (range of subnets) 192.168.1.32 - 192.168.1.62 => (broadcast address) 192.168.1.63

192.168.1.64  => (range of subnets) 192.168.1.64 - 192.168.1.94 => (broadcast address) 192.168.1.95

192.168.1.92  => (range of subnets) 192.168.1.96 - 192.168.1.128 => (broadcast address) 192.168.1.129

192.168.1.124 => (range of subnets) 192.168.1.130 - 192.168.1.162 => (broadcast address) 192.168.1.163

is it all right? If not, could you please point where I've made a mistake?

Comment: You need to use a /27 subnet mask for all networks, giving you an address space of 32. So the first network is .0, .32, .64, .96 and .128. First usable is +1 and last usable is +32 -2 (e.g. 96+32-2=126) and broadcast is 32-1 (e.g. 128+32-1=159). All of your subnets have errors, except for the first one.

Comment: 1. 192.168.1.0/27: .0 - .1 to .30 - .31 | 2. 192.168.1.32/27: .32 - .33 to .62 - .63 | 3. 192.168.1.64/27: .64 - .65 to .94 - .95 | 4.192.168.1.96/27: .96 - .97 to .126 - .127 | 5. 192.168.1.128/27: .128 - .129 to .158 - .159 (first is network range - second is usable address space - last is broadcast)

Answer (score 0):

you should use another subnet mask. example 255.255.255.224
The default gateway address will be set following

```
192.168.1.30/255.255.255.224 (1.31 will be broadcast address)
192.168.1.62/255.255.255.224 (1.63 will be broadcast address)
192.168.1.94/255.255.255.224 (1.95 will be broadcast address)
192.168.1.126/255.255.255.224 (1.127 will be broadcast address)
192.168.1.158/255.255.255.224 (1.159 will be broadcast address)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The ip address is 192.168.1.0 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0 were included in the task so did I receive the wrong content/reference?

Comment: you can use some subnets within 192.168.1.0/24.
192.168.1.0/27, 192.168.1.32/27, ...